# How to split robot testcases using colon, so that each will be treated as separate testcase?

Tags: robotframework

I have 3 test cases which will test the same functionality. It will use same keywords as shown below.

Instead of writing three different test cases "test-1151,test-2125,test-2126", I want to write one test case separated with colons as shown below. But robot should treat this as three seperate test case and it should show pass/fail test case count accordingly.

**test.robot:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library           lib.test

*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

*** Test Cases ***

test-1151:test-2125:test-2126
    [Documentation]  test_sample
    [Tags]  sanity
    Install Adobe software
    Launch the app
```

If I run the above robot file, robot is taking "test-1151:test-2125:test-2126" as one test case. How to tell robot to treat this as three different test cases (separated with colon)?

Comment: Why would you want to run the exact same test three times with three different names? Do you really need to run the exact test three times, or do you just need it to appear in a report three times?

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't want to run same test case three times. I need to have count that "test-1151:test-2125:test-2126" test cases executed and its got passed/failed details in report.

Comment: How can you count that a test case executed if you don't execute the test? Have you considered using tags, since tag statistics appear in the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you turn the detail of the test case into a keyword?  Then write three test cases that call the keyword?

This might be an alternative option for you:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style

Basically have one test template which would be the same, maybe have some arguments for parameters that will change based on test cases.  You can then have many test cases doing exactly the same or slightly different things in a short and concise notation.

Comment: This is a good idea. But problem is 'keywords' section will become lengthier, if we are adding more similar test cases. if we have test case split option, it will be good, i think.

Comment: to be honest having the same test case a bunch of times is strange in itself but I don't know your use case.  Why would the keywords section become longer?  If you're doing the same thing, it would be static.  The only change would be an additional test case in the test case section for every repetition you wish to do

Comment: Added data-driven tests option to answer

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what your real goals are. It seems that you want to see three items in the report, "test-1151", "test-2125", and "test-2126", but that you actually only want to run that test once.

I'm guessing that those names correspond to either a test plan or an item in a ticketing system of some sort.

My recommendation is to use tags to tag your test. You can give the test any name you want, and then give it tags for the names you want to see in the report. Once the test runs, the report can give you statistics based on tag.

For example:

```
test-1151:test-2125:test-2126
    [Documentation]  test_sample
    [Tags]  sanity  test-1151  test-2125  test-2126
    Install Adobe software
    Launch the app
```

To answer your specific question of whether you can have this one test reported three times, the answer is "no". It will show up in the logs and report as a single test. However, the report also includes test status by tag, so you will see one item in the report for each tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we use the tags, will robot report show Testcase count as 3?

Comment: The best way to answer that question is for you to try it and see. Robot will report a pass or fail once for every test that actually runs. It will also show statistics for each tag.